# Sending an email if a File in a folder is older than 1 Minute else do not send anything in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

Here is my code, which sends an email and creates a good subject if a file exists however it sends the email continuously even if there are no files present. I want to use something like "if file.exist then smtp send".

```
$smtpServer = "test.local"
$smtpTo = "test@test.com";
$messageSubject = "Urgent check....!"
$Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpFrom, $smtpTo
$Message.Subject = $messageSubject
$content = Get-ChildItem '\\test\test1\test2\*.txt' |
           Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)}
$Message.IsBodyHtml = $true
$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$style = $style + "</style>"
$Message.Body = Get-ChildItem '\\test\test1\test2\*.txt' |
                Select-Object -Property "Name", "LastWriteTime" |
                Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)} |
                ConvertTo-Html -Head $style
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient ($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `$content` is empty, and only send mail if it's not.

```bsh
...
$content = Get-ChildItem '\\test\test1\test2\*.txt' |
           Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)}

if ($content) {
    $Message = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpFrom, $smtpTo
    ...
    $Message.Body = $content |
                    Select-Object "Name", "LastWriteTime" |
                    ConvertTo-Html -Head $style

    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtpServer
    ...
}
```

On more recent PowerShell versions you could use the [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet instead of fumbling around with `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` objects. The general approach would be the same, though.

```bsh
...
$content = Get-ChildItem '\\test\test1\test2\*.txt' |
           Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)}

if ($content) {
    $body = $content |
            Select-Object "Name", "LastWriteTime" |
            ConvertTo-Html -Head $style

    Send-MailMessage -To $smtpTo ... -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $smtpServer ...
}
```